# Create Temporary Table in a Stored Procedure Including "WITH" [MySQL]

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure written in MySQL, and I want to store its results in a temporary table. Here is the code:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE GetRequiredItemsCount(
    IN item VARCHAR(16),
    IN parent_item_count INT)

    BEGIN
/*      DROP TABLE IF EXISTS required_items;
        CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE required_items AS */
        
            WITH RECURSIVE bom_temp AS (

                SELECT bom.item_id, bom.component_id, bom.bom_multiplier
                FROM bom
                WHERE bom.item_id = item
                
                UNION ALL

                SELECT child.item_id, child.component_id, child.bom_multiplier
                FROM bom_temp parent
                    JOIN bom child ON parent.component_id = child.item_id
                )

            SELECT DISTINCT component_id, SUM(bom_multiplier)*parent_item_count
            FROM bom_temp
            GROUP BY component_id;
    END$$
DELIMITER;
```

It is currently working, but when I remove the comments from the part `CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE required_items AS`, it raises error.

I think the problem is the use of `WITH`, but I could not find any similar cases on the net.

I would appreciate your suggestions and comments, thanks!

P.S: "bom" table is generated as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE bom (  item_id VARCHAR(16),
                    component_id VARCHAR(16),
                    bom_multiplier INT NOT NULL,
                    PRIMARY KEY (item_id, component_id));

INSERT INTO bom (item_id, component_id, bom_multiplier)
VALUES  ("001", "002", 1),
        ("001", "003", 1),
        ("002", "004", 3),
        ("002", "005", 3);
```

Comment: which version of mysql are you using ? and pls share the error you have got

Comment: Its working fine .. can you have a look here : https://dbfiddle.uk/YRL2dfrf

Comment: @SelVazi I noticed the problem thanks to you, the error message was saying that the column name was incorrect for SUM(bom_multiplier)*parent_item_count. So appended AS required_amount to the end of that line and it worked. I am not sure why it was not working on my environment and working in the online interpreter you shared. My version is: 8.0.31.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message was pointing out the incorrect column name for `SELECT DISTINCT component_id, SUM(bom_multiplier)*parent_item_count`. The problem was solved when I appended `AS required_amount` to that line.